New wheels feel sluggish... is it the cartridge bearings?
I bought a Mavic Aksium wheelset to replace the failing ("gritty" worn cups/cones, shot freehub bearings) pair on my bike, I specifically went for a wheelset with cartridge bearings because I did not want to have replace an entire wheel because of a damaged cup again.
After a few days with them I can't shake the feeling these wheels are little more sluggish feeling than the previous wheels.
These wheels are lighter, the tyres are also racier and significantly lighter than the puncture resistant types on previous wheels.
While the new wheels spin smoothly that is not a real measure of drag, cartridge bearings are said to be draggier than cup and cone style due to the seal and maybe other things?
These wheels also use a bushing for freehub instead of bearings, maybe more draggy, supposedly more reliable which again I opted for because of the failure of the old freehub.
I was curious what kind of wheels the pros use, the Dura-ace C60 was mentioned as a popular choice for high speed and low drag... to my surprise this €2k wheelset features cup and cone bearings.
Could cartridge bearings really be this bad?
OTOH if tight seals are the main cause of this drag couldn't I just remove them?

Did you measure any performance on some timed segments? Or is it just the feel? That can be deceiving.

Sluggishness can also be influenced by the tires and their pressures. If you come from rigid puncture proof tires and switch to supple performance tire at lower pressure (and larger section), it can feel sluggish, but that's doesn't mean it's a problem.

If you remove the bearing seals, you may be shopping for a new set of bearings soon as well.

Its just the feel, could be totally imaginary.

The old tyres were 25c in rear, 23c in front. New are both 25c.
Just discovered they have a  narrower recommended range of pressure and a higher min pressure. The tyres feel softer between the fingers with a similar amount of resistance from the pump... it has no gauge so have no idea of actual pressures.
So yeah, probably heavily related to tyre differences. Also night and day improvement when it comes to cornering.

@MaplePanda Since they will need to be replaced eventually, I had a look into replacement bearings.
There are a number of types of cartridge bearings in a given size, you can get shielded types which offer less protection than sealed but lower friction.
Bearings are quite cheap on aliexpress, I might try a set of them for the next replacements and see how they perform and if they last.

Aside: I bought some Aksiums cheap too - they're surprisingly fragile wheels for heavier riders like me, so consider carrying spare spokes and tools on a ride.

To update: I aquired a pump with a gauge, pumped to max 7.5 bar, now it plain feels faster, smoother too.

Feel is hard to troubleshoot because it is subjective. However, just because it's subjective does not mean it's not real.
The original question speaks of the difference between cartridge bearings and cup/cone bearings.
A cartridge bearing does have more friction than cup and cone bearings.

"Friction Resistance in Bicycle Wheel Bearings"

It is noted that the friction for bearing seals may be high as new bearings were used. Seals bed-in with use and their friction therefore reduces.

Though there is a difference in bearings is this the sluggishness felt by the rider? I don't know for sure but I doubt it.
Many factors contribute to how a wheel feels.
Here are a few of them:
Lateral stiffness
Lateral stiffness is a metric that has more than one contributing factor.

Rim width


Lateral stiffness in a rim or wheel speaks to the level of movement from side to side. A wider rim doesn’t flex from side to side as much as a narrow rim, so it can be characterized as having more lateral stiffness.
Laterally stiff rims feel more responsive during powerful accelerations like sprinting; you get a direct power transfer. Steering and handling feel sharper, but this could also have the feeling of harshness under some conditions.
There are many factors that influence the stiffness of a wheel: spoke count, gauge, material type, and lacing pattern, however, the rim offers the most dramatic change. Creating a wider, deeper, thicker rim, especially made with carbon fiber, will increase stiffness. Further, the thickness and layup design heavily influence the feel of the rim, which is what makes carbon such an exciting material to work with. You could build two identical wheelsets with every factor identical except for the layup design, and get a measurably different stiffness. Lateral Stiffness Test


Rim type

Spoke type

Steel, straight, single butted, double butted
Aluminum
Titanium - generally decreased stiffness as Titanium is now for flexibility.
Stainless steel, straight, single butted, double butted
Carbon fiber, lots of kinds


Offers excellent stiffness and weight savings, making them ideal for high-performance road bikes. However, they are more expensive. "All about Bike Spokes"

Spoke Gauge
Spokes come in a variety of thicknesses. Generally, thicker spokes are stronger and heavier than thinner spokes.
Lacing Patterns

Radial - spokes run directly from the hub to the rim without crossing each other. Radial spokes provide a stiffer wheel.
Cross lacing


2-Cross: Spokes cross each other twice between the hub and the rim. It offers a balance between strength and weight.
3-Cross: Spokes cross each other three times. This pattern is the most popular for its strength and durability, suitable for most riding conditions.
4-Cross: Spokes cross four times, providing maximum strength and durability. It is often used for heavy-duty applications like downhill or touring bikes.
"The Role of Bicycle Spokes in Ensuring Strength, Stability, and Efficiency of Cycling Performance"
Generally, more crossing equals greater strength and less stiffness.

Spoke Count
Wheels may have from 18 to 36 spokes. Generally, more spokes means a stronger and heavier wheel
Spoke Tension
Poorly built wheels can have spokes that are not tensioned correctly.
These are some of the factors that can contribute in wheel construction. Differences in tires and in inflation often have a large effect on feel.

Just to put some numbers on this, 30km/h on 700c corresponds to 235rpm. At that angular velocity, the difference between cup & cone and sealed bearing is 27-2.5=24.5 N•mm. Power is angular velocity times torque, and so the power loss here is 0.096 watts. We should double this because the graph is per hub, and so the net loss is 0.192 watts. That’s probably not a big deal when you’re putting in ~192 watts to propel yourself at 30km/h…

@MaplePanda Thanks!! I knew it was a small difference but you have shown how tiny it really is.

Definitely a small effect, but to be honest 0.2W sounds a little low. I was expecting something more in the 1-2W zone total. Not sure if I calculated wrong or if the graph is just inaccurate.
